# Dynamic organizational chart

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, chart-web-part

I'm in a bit of a pickle and don't really know if can solve my problem with SharePoint.
My company wants to build an organizational chart (easy, right ?) that will allow us to know every job that we have and ultimately where we have open positions.

So we want to build a chart just like the one I link to this post, knowing it can be dynamic. By that, I mean that at any point, a regional manager for instance can add a new country organization, a manager can add a new employee position, etc... (we don't care - for now - about knowing who is filling the position, we just want to know the job titles we have)

So first, we want to know back at HQ the organizational structures of each region and country. After this, we want to be able to flag if a given position is filled or not and be able to collate the number of open positions globally (e.g. something like "3 manager positions available | 3 employees positions available" etc... and then go into details for which region, country, it's opened).

I'm in the process of gathering the data on an Excel file. I'm sort of struggling to see how I can then translate this to SharePoint. I checked what I can do with importing my Excel in Visio and then publishing to SharePoint, but it's just a frozen picture, so not really a solution.

So do you think this is even feasible with SharePoint and if so, do you have any tips at how I might tackle this challenge ?
PS: We have SharePoint online. I don't know a lot about SharePoint designer, but I can always learn :)

[image: Organization example]

Comment: Here is an article how to build one with SharePoint,Excel and Visio: https://en.share-gate.com/blog/create-organizational-chart-sharepoint-office-2013

Comment: @LarsFastrup Thanks for your reply. I saw that article before. What I got from it is that every time I want to modify something I'd have to do it via Visio. And that's not possible in my company (basically users don't want to and don't have the time). The ideal here would be to have Visio as a starting point and then do everything from SharePoint..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create List structure and add data into list from excel and the use Jquery Charts to achieve your organization charts.

**Step 1 : List Structure**

*Method 1 : Flat Structure*

You can use single list to save all your organization level details in the SharePoint. So now your column names would be Level 1, Level 2, Level 3 and so on. Now you can even copy paste your excel data to SharePoint list and save data

*Method 2 : Normalized Structure*

You can create parent child relationship maintained by different list, which would make your data normalized. You need to create Level 1 List and add details in Title column. Create Level 2 List and take a lookup column from level 1 list so maintaining parent child relationship. Normalized structure would be cumbersome for now but it would have long term benefits and flexibility

**Step 2 : Drawing Chart**

*Method 1 : Jquery Charts*

Fetch data from SharePoint List using Rest API or CSOM on client side.

[CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

[Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)

Create either JSON Structure or HTML Structure depending on Widget or Plugin for Org chart you using.

Few of the reference are below and you can find many more options online...

[dabeng/OrgChart](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart)

[caprica/jquery-orgchart](https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart)

[Google Org Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart)

[Highcharts Org Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer)

*Method 2 :  SSRS*

You can also use SSRS to achieve this but the output is not as elegant as Jquery plugins would provide you.

[Recursive Hierarchy Group in SSRS 2008](http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.in/2010/08/recursive-hierarchy-group-in-ssrs-2008.html)

[SSRS Org Charts](https://creately.com/diagram/h8vvxnvi/SSRS%20ORG%20CHART)

Comment: Wow, that's a really detailed answer, thanks. I just checked the various links you put, and from what I could gather), it seems perfect for me  (dabeng and Google's charts seem the most suitable. I need to gather and validate my data and I will try it out ! i'll let you know how I'm faring when I get to this point. 
Thanks again !

Comment: You can mark as answer to close the query.